# Function to check plan

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm creating an application that allow the user to draw out a floor plan. It gives them a 12 x 8 grid and lets them click up to 50 sqaures. It stops them when they get to 50 but they can click on an already selected sqaure to turn it blank and then choose another.

What I need to be able to do is check the plan. They can't have any gaps in it. All squares have the accesable from all other square on only in the four main directions (no diagonals).

Is there some kind of function that could image a man standing in square one and making sure he can visit all the other squares.

I'm willing to use php or JavaScript if required. Is there anything already around that will do that, or would somebody be able to assist me.

There code for creating the floor plan is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Plan</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
      var count=0;

      function plan(id)
      {
        var obj = document.getElementById(id);

        if(obj.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(0, 0, 0)")
        {
          if(count <= 49)
          {
            count++;
          }
          else
          {
             alert('You can have a maximum of 50');
            count++;
          }
        }
        else if(obj.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
        {
          count--;
        }
        if(count <= 50)
        {
          obj.style.backgroundColor = (obj.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") ? "#ff0000" : "#000000";
          obj.style.color = (obj.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") ? "#000000" : "#ffffff";
        }
        if (count>50)
        {
            count--;
        }
      }

      function number()
      {
        var room_number=0;
        col=0;
        row="a";
        for (var i=1; i<97; i++)
        {
          col++;
          if (i<97)
          {
            row="h";
          }
          if (i<85)
          {
            row="g";
          }
          if (i<73)
          {
            row="f";
          }
          if (i<61)
          {
            row="e";
          }
          if (i<49)
          {
            row="d";
          }
          if (i<37)
          {
            row="c";
          }
          if (i<25)
          {
            row="b";
          }
          if (i<13)
          {
            row="a";
          }

          if (col>12)
          {
            col=1;
          }
          var room = document.getElementById(row+col);
          if (room.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
          {
            room_number++;
            room.textContent=room_number;
          }
          else
          {
            room.textContent="";
          }
        }
      }
    //-->
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color: #000000; width: 386px; margin: 10px auto 0;">
<?php
    $l=0;
    $j=0;

    for ($i=0; $i<96; $i++)
    {
      $l++;
      $j++;
      if ($j<97)
      {
        $letter=h;
      }
      if ($j<85)
      {
        $letter=g;
      }
      if ($j<73)
      {
        $letter=f;
      }
      if ($j<61)
      {
        $letter=e;
      }
      if ($j<49)
      {
        $letter=d;
      }
      if ($j<37)
      {
        $letter=c;
      }
      if ($j<25)
      {
        $letter=b;
      }
      if ($j<13)
      {
        $letter=a;
      }

      if ($l>12)
      {
        $l=1;
      }
      $border="2px 0 0 2px";
      if ($l==12)
      {
        $border="2px 2px 0 2px";
      }
      if ($j>84)
      {
        $border="2px 0 2px 2px";
      }
      if ($j==96)
      {
          $border="2px 2px 2px 2px";
      }
?>
      <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; border-style: solid; border-color: #ffffff; border-width: <?=$border;?>; float: left; background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 700;" id="<?=$letter, $l;?>" onclick="plan('<?=$letter, $l;?>');">&nbsp;</div>
<?php
    }
?>
    <input type="button" value="Done" onclick="number();"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Richard, I would put your boxes in an multidimensional array so that you can then go through the array and you would know if the "move" is possible. if E3 is a floor then either E2 E4 D3 or F3 need to be active... I hope I understand what your doing.

Comment: I had thought of doing it like that but is E3 is active and A9 is active, I need to check you can get from one to the next. Just checking that each square has one adjacent mean you could have up to 25 'islands'.

Comment: Your grid would be setup to start at one position say A1 and end at F10... It would check your grid, if A1 is active then A2 or B2 has to be active... So, it would check those two spots... If they weren't active it would give an error... It would do this for each grid location until the last one. If it ever finds that a logical move is not found it errors out. Which really it wouldn't matter where it starts and ends, it just goes through the array until it fails or until the array is over.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I'll try it out over the weekend and let you know how I get one.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is basically a [Connected Graph problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedGraph.html), but in a much simpler manner - all you care about is that for each square chosen, if it is not the only one chosen so far, it has a neighbor square that is not blank.
You can either make sure this invariant holds after each square marking, but you would have to also test for it after turning a square into a blank, by making sure each of the now-blank square neighbors has a chosen neighbor.

Code-wise, your current solution seems a bit lacking.
You are relying on the square background to identify if it's chosen or not, which is not a great idea - imagine later you want to control this colors from a CSS file or allow multiple colors. It will get messy.

I suggest you create a data structure that will hold the grid, and for each square hold the data representing the state for that square. For example, a 12x8 matrix, that holds 0 if the square is blank and 1 if it is chosen. That way, searching for a square neighbors is much easier than traversing the DOM. Give a coordinate for each drawn square in the range of (1..12, 1..8), and when creating the document through PHP assign the coordinate to each square's `onclick` action. For example, the PHP drawing could be done with something like this:

```
<?php
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; ++$i) {
      for ($j = 1; $j <= 8; ++$j) {
      ?>
      <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; border-style: solid; border-color: #ffffff; border-width: <?=$border;?>; float: left; background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 700;" id="<?=$letter, $l;?>" onclick="plan(<?=$i;?>, <?=$j;?>, '<?=$letter, $l;?>');">&nbsp;</div>
      <?php
      }
    }
?>
```

and then handle the `($i, $j)` coordinates given to `plan()` to update the right square in the JavaScript matrix representing the grid.

You may initialize the JavaScript matrix as follows [(wrapped up in a nice jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/LNsUC/2/):

```
var maxY = 12;
var maxX = 8;
var grid = new Array(maxY);
for (var i = 0; i < maxY; ++i) {
  grid[i] = new Array(maxX);
  for (var j = 0; j < maxX; ++j) {
    grid[i][j] = 0;   
  }
}

function checkConnectedSquare(grid, y, x) {
  // one of the neighbors must be chosen
  return (x > 0 && grid[y][x-1] == 1)
         || (x < maxX-1 && grid[y][x+1] == 1)
         || (y > 0 && grid[y-1][x] == 1)
         || (y < maxY-1 && grid[y+1][x] == 1);   
}

function checkConnected(grid) {
  var countChosenSquares = 0;
  var isConnected = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < maxY; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < maxX; ++j) {
            if (grid[i][j] == 1) {
              if (!checkConnectedSquare(grid, i, j)) {
                isConnected = false;
              }
              countChosenSquares++;
            }
        }
    }
  // if no squares were chosen or only one, the grid is 'connected'
  // or every square that is chosen is connected.
  return (countChosenSquares <= 1 || isConnected);
}

// test the code

function printGrid(grid) {
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < maxY; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < maxX; ++j) {
           html += grid[i][j] + ' ';
        }
        html += '<br />';
    }
    document.body.innerHTML = html;
}

grid[3][6] = 1;
grid[3][7] = 1;

// should be true
console.log(checkConnectedSquare(grid, 3, 6));

// should be true
console.log(checkConnectedSquare(grid, 3, 7));

// should be false
console.log(checkConnectedSquare(grid, 2, 5));

// should be true
console.log(checkConnected(grid));

grid[2][5] = 1;
// should be false
console.log(checkConnected(grid));

grid[2][5] = 0;
grid[3][6] = 0;
// should be true
console.log(checkConnected(grid));

printGrid(grid);
```

As a bonus, you can also hold a reference to the DOM element representing this square in order to easily update the grid.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to fit this into my current program. I assume I can leave out the first of the functions above since I'm only interested in validating the gird when the user has finished. 
When they click done, it checks the gird and either says "Not allowed" and leaves them to fix it, or if it is allowed then it numbers it.

Comment: @RichardYoung: I wouldn't do that because the second function uses the first one. The first function is used to validate a single square, and the second one makes sure the whole grid is ok.
What you need to do is hold your grid in a data structure similar to what I described, so you will be able to query it for validation. Otherwise, you will have to deal with a lot of hacky code to do so, and will have a hard time extending it further as the project goes.

Comment: I'll have to forget it then. I can't do it like that. There is a need to have two or more remote squares that you then join up. I can't work with it if it validates as it goes on.

Comment: Then just call the validate function when the user presses submit instead of every marking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    function WhatNeedsActive($row,$square){
        $baserow = '1'; //Cannot goto row 0
        $maxrow = '4'; //Cannot goto row 5
        $base_square = '1';
        $max_square = '10';
        $active_squares = array(); 
        if ($row != $baserow){
            $active_squares[] = "Row: " . ($row - 1) . " Square: " . $square;
        }
        if ($row != $maxrow){
            $active_squares[] = "Row: " . ($row + 1) . " Square: " . $square;
        }
        if ($square != $max_square){
            $active_squares[] = "Row: " . $row . " Square: " . ($square + 1);
        }
        if ($square != $base_square){
            $active_squares[] = "Row: " . $row . " Square: " . ($square - 1);
        }
        var_dump ($active_squares);
    }
    WhatNeedsActive('2','5');

?>
```